# Why is ng-repeat being commented out my MEAN stack app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I am trying to do a simple tracer bullet with my MEAN stack application. I am stuck on trying to get my app.js file in my server to communicate with my app.js in my views. Here is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="allInOne">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/normalize.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/XXX.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/src/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/src/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!--  header  -->
<header>
  <h1 class="text-center">XXX</h1>
  <h4 class="text-center">All In One</h4>
</header>

<!--  containers / content  -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 content-prime">
            <h3>
                .col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8.
            </h3>
            <div class="notice-pre-content">
                holy crap here's an alert, or factoid
            </div>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 nav-prime"><h3>.col-xs-6 .col-md-4.</h3><p>Navigation on the right can go here. Yep yep yep. On the right side. Here it is. Yaaargghh. Yep. Yep. Yep. Navigation on the right can go here. Yep yep yep. On the right side. Here it is. Yaaargghh. Yep. Yep. Yep.</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">Bot left, m8.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
        <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
        <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><h5>.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4. Bot right.</h5></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <ul ng-contoller="testController">
        <li ng-repeat="element in list"> {{element}} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- footer -->
<footer>
        <h5 class="text-center">link dump: google+, facebook, twitter, green initiative, member fdic </h5>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem is within the ng-controller but am not sure.

```
<div>
    <ul ng-contoller="testController">
        <li ng-repeat="element in list"> {{element}} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

server/app.js

```
let express = require("express");

let app = express();

app.use( express.static(__dirname + "/../views") );

let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let jsonParser = bodyParser.json();


app.get("/test", (request, response) => {
    response.json( ["Hello", "World"]);
});
app.listen(81, 'codeone2016.erikshafer.me');
```

views/src/app.js

```
var app = angular.module('allInOne', []);

app.controller('testController', ($scope, $http) => {
    $http.get('/test')
        .success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        $scope.results = response.results;
});
```

Comment: Because you didnt define nor any elements are present in the $scope.list =[]; array in scope.

Comment: I  assume you wan to display `$scope.results` but instead you are using list as data source in your `ng-repeat` . Just try replacing it with results

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: We decided to go with a different approach but thank you very much!

Comment: different approach ? wasn't that the issue ?